# How to study the calculation of scattering amplitudes in particle physics?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, resource-recommendations, scattering, s-matrix-theory, scattering-cross-section

I am looking for literature on the topic of calculating scattering amplitudes for particle physics processes, but this is a very big subject.

I have studied introductory particle physics before, as well as a lot of quantum mechanics and a decent bit of QFT. I know I am missing some theory such as how to derive the Feynman rules from a Feynman diagram, but it is hard to know where to start reading. Is there any good summary that describes what theory is needed to be able to learn the techniques surrounding the computation of scattering amplitudes? I am looking for something like: https://arxiv.org/abs/2111.00205, except on an even more elementary level.

Edit: Thank you all for the suggestions! The notes on QFT and amplitudes are already very helpful.

Comment: Just to be clear, are you comfortable with Quantum Field Theory already?

Comment: Yes, I should have added that. I have a decent bit of QFT as well.

Comment: You derive Feynman rules from a Lagrangian, not a Feynman diagram.

Comment: First, you say that you don't know yet how to derive the Feynman rules. In that case I feel you may still need QFT background. I *personally* think that the first five chapters of Weinberg's "The Quantum Theory of Fields" must be studied by anyone going into QFT.  I also think that Schwartz' textbook is a good one, because it already teaches you LSZ reduction at the begining.

Comment: Finally, regarding scattering amplitudes themselves, there is a whole field devoted to calculational methods known exactly as "amplitudes". There is a chapter on it in Schwartz' book, but I think better references might be the lecture notes by Elvang (https://arxiv.org/abs/1308.1697) and Taylor (https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.05670)

Comment: Calculating scattering amplitudes is a huge subject and there are many special techniques that can be applied in certain circumstances depending on what subfield you are interested in. But as a baseline, in my opinion you absolutely must be comfortable computing a tree-level 2-2 scattering amplitude using Feynman diagrams in QED before it makes sense to think about any more advanced methods. For example, problems 59.1-3 in [Srednicki's draft book](https://web.physics.ucsb.edu/~mark/ms-qft-DRAFT.pdf). The book has a series of prerequisites for each chapter so you can fill in what you need.

Comment: The authors of the review in the pdf below want to bridge a gap. Perhaps it is your gap. Review:  https://arxiv.org/pdf/1308.1697.pdf